# AS3: Looping through a ByteArray

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've seen two different ways of looping through a ByteArray, one way by using `readByte()` and the other way of just using the index `[i]`:

readByte/writeByte method:

```
var value:int;
var l:uint = sourceByteArray.length;
for (var i:uint=0; i<l; i++) {
    value = sourceByteArray.readByte();
    ...
    targetByteArray.writeByte(value);
}
```

index method:

```
var value:int;
var l:uint = sourceByteArray.length;
for (var i:uint=0; i<l; i++) {
    value = sourceByteArray[i];
    ...
    targetByteArray[i] = value;
}
```

Do they do the same thing? Is one way any better than the other?

Edit: I've done some more testing and it seems the index method is about 1.5x faster. Is there any reason to do the readByte method?

Comment: The only difference I can see is when you read past the end of the array: readByte throws an EOF error, whereas [i] throws an index error?

Comment: You can also try **Vector.<int>**, it might work even faster.